# JSON Result download zip file does not work

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, download, zip

The code below works perfectly in my local development machine, but in hosting machine doesn't.

The behavior in hosting machine is show this line browser's in URL Adress when it finish instead of download the file:

http://www.dcsyslogin.com/Index/Download?fileGuid=3797ed2d-4239-48b9-b228-165a890c89f5&mimeType=application/zip,%20application/octet-stream&filename=OT_19.zip

I've test this in firefox and chrome with the same result.

In my local machine works fine downloading de ZIP dile.

Some suggestions what it can be?

Thanks

In view:

```
<a href="javascript: RunReportTodos('@Url.Action("DescargarFotos","Index", new { Id = Model.Id })')" , class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Está seguro(a) de bajar archivos la OT');">Bajar archivos y fotos</a>
```

Complete view:

```
@model DCSystem.Areas.VSX.Models.AdminOTModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VSX - Administrar OT";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("AdminOT", "Index", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @ViewBag.Title
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Estado)
            @Html.Label("Seleccione OT :", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x =>
                  x.Id,
(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.selectItemsOts,
new
{
    @class = "form-control selectpickerOT",
    data_live_search = "true",
    title = "Vacío",
    onchange = "this.form.submit();",
})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id)
            </div>
        </div>
        @if (Model.Id > 0)
        {
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="left">
                        @*@Html.ActionLink("Procesar formularios", "Generar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de generar OT') && DisplayProgressMessage();" })*@
                        <a href="javascript: RunReportTodos('@Url.Action("DescargarFotos","Index", new { Id = Model.Id })')" , class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return confirm('Está seguro(a) de bajar archivos la OT');">Bajar archivos y fotos</a>

                         @if (Model.Estado == DCSystem.Areas.VSX.Models.EstadosOT.ARCHIVADA)
                        {
                            @Html.ActionLink("Des Archivar", "Archivar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de Desarchivar OT');" })
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             if (Model.Estado == DCSystem.Areas.VSX.Models.EstadosOT.ENPROCESO)
                             {
                                @Html.ActionLink("Publicar", "Publicar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de publicar OT');" })
                                @Html.ActionLink("Archivar", "Archivar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de archivar OT');" })
                                @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Eliminar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de eliminar OT');" })
                             }
                             if (Model.Estado == DCSystem.Areas.VSX.Models.EstadosOT.MINISTERIO)
                             {
                                @Html.ActionLink("Activar", "Publicar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de archivar OT');" })
                                @Html.ActionLink("Archivar", "Archivar", new { id = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return confirm('Esta seguro(a) de archivar OT');" })
                             }
                         }


                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="NombreArchivo" type="file" name="UploadedFile" class="btn btn-primary" accept=".zip" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" onclick="return DisplayProgressMessage();" name="Submit" value="Subir archivo" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>
}
<script>
    $('.selectpickerOT').selectpicker({
        liveSearch: true
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RunReportTodos(reportUrl) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("body").addClass("submit-progress-bg");
        }, 1);

        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".submit-progress").removeClass("hidden");
        }, 1);

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: reportUrl,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                window.location = "/Index/Download?fileGuid=" + response.FileGuid +
                   "&mimeType=" + response.MimeType + "&filename=" + response.FileName;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(".submit-progress").addClass("hidden");
                }, 1);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("body").removeClass("submit-progress-bg");
                }, 1);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult DescargarFotos(int id)
{
    var t = GenerarAsync(id);
    VSX_OT OT = db.VSX_OTs.Find(id);
    string OTDir = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("\\UserFiles\\VSX");
    OTDir += "\\OT_" + OT.OT.ToString();
    OTDir += "\\FOTOS\\";

    string codunicotemporal = Guid.NewGuid() + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");

    string zipTemporal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("//UserFiles//" + codunicotemporal) + ".zip";

    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(OTDir, zipTemporal);

    var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(zipTemporal);

    System.IO.File.Delete(zipTemporal);

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(OTDir))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(OTDir, true);
    }

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        Session[handle] = stream.ToArray();
        return new JsonResult()
        {
            Data = new
            {
                FileGuid = handle,
                MimeType = "application/zip, application/octet-stream",
                FileName = "OT_" + OT.OT.ToString() + ".zip"
            }
        };
    }


}

public ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string mimeType, string filename)
{
    if (Session[fileGuid] != null)
    {
        byte[] data = Session[fileGuid] as byte[];
        Session.Remove(fileGuid);  // Cleanup session data
        return File(data, mimeType, filename);
    }
    else
    {
        // Log the error if you want
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I added MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue:

```
return new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = new
                    {
                        FileGuid = handle,
                        MimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip,
                        FileName = "OT_" + OT.OT.ToString() + ".zip",
                        MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
                    }
                };
```

And change the process to get a smaller zip file: from 90000 Kb to 10000 kb.